# Is it a good idea to use Page Object Model with TestComplete?

Tags: automated-testing, page-objects, testcomplete

We're using TestComplete at this company, and we're intertwining a bit of scripting in our Keyword tests. I'm thinking about just turning it into just Page Object Model type tests since the recording can be tedious.

Has anyone gone through a big project with Page Object Model with TestComplete and can speak to its merits/demerits?

Comment: What exactly are you testing with TestComplete? and why did you think of going to Page Object Modelling? just trying to analyze the question before I put an answer.

Comment: @DEnumber50    

I'm testing a Silverlight application that has functionality separated into tabs. 

I'm considering trying to use Page Object Model because I realize I'm actually able to write scripts faster than work with Keyword Tests, and POM seems like a decent pattern to follow for this project (each tab is a page, essentially). I'm fairly new to automated testing, but have programming experience, so I just want to make sure I'm steering in an appropriate direction for maintainable tests.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes. It's documented in [official documentation](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/55305/).**

> Also you can find an example [here](http://community.smartbear.com/t5/Functional-Web-Testing/Page-Object-Pattern-with-TestComplete/td-p/89188) to understand better / start with.

Comment: OP doesn't look for a simple example. He wanted to know whether it works well for larger scale projects.

Comment: @Thomas I think POM is a pattern designed to make automated tests scale better for larger software products, certainly where tests re-use views/pages in the tests. The POM pattern should make the test more maintainable. As SmartBear has basic examples in their documentation, it seems that the POM pattern can be implemented with TestComplete and their tool chain.

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal: you say "is designed to", OP wants to know if the design holds. You say "should make", OP want to know if it really does. You say "it seems", OP want to know if it really does. IMHO OP wants to get away from all the marketing promises and see whether it has been proven in practice.

Comment: @Thomas You are right, but I think the main question is if it works with TestComplete. The second question does POM work on large scale projects is maybe better asked as a separate question. I am working on a 4mil LOC project and we now have around 200 CodedUI tests following the POM pattern. I would say it works pretty damn good :) But the pro's and cons are to much for a comment here and I cant talk for TestComplete :(

Answer (score 0):

For future testers who stumble across this question:

Yes - you are able to use the Page Object Model design pattern with TestComplete. The way I went about doing this was by almost entirely using TestCompletes Scripts. I set up one folder for Page Objects and general/navigation functions, while another folder contained the Tests themselves. I was able to quickly build the Page Objects by taking advantage of TestCompletes record script functionality to access the pages elements and then wrapped these in their own functions (after tidying up the automatically generated code, of course).

This scaled quite well for a medium sized multi-page web application.