# Design patterns specific for test automation

Tags: automated-testing, test-design, test-automation-framework, pom

Software engineering has many design patterns, including Adaptors, Abstract Factories, Decorators etc. Test automation, as a branch of software engineering, can use same patterns but has also its own design patterns, to name a few:

- [Page Object](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) - wraps an HTML page, or fragment, with an application-specific API, allowing you to manipulate page elements without digging around in the HTML.
- [Screenplay](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Beyond-Page-Objects-Test-Automation-Serenity-Screenplay) - originally invented to [address limitations](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27488/screen-play-vs-page-object-pattern) of Page Object pattern: an Actor have Abilities to perform certain Tasks composed of Actions that interact with Elements of a Screen
- [Features and Testers](http://www.joekearney.co.uk/posts/guava-testlib-example) - originally invented by Guava team to test collections: different implementations share similar Features, so one test (caller Tester) for a specific feature can be used to test multiply implementations. It can be used to verify output of end-to-end scenarios as well.

What are other design patterns specific to automating tests?

I am thinking more of design patterns related to object-oriented programming, describing relations between classes and interfaces.

Comment: Although interesting, I flagged the question as too broad. It will probably end up as an endless list of arguable design patterns.

Comment: @beatngu13 That would be we would need to close other similar questions as well, e.g. about books: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/42/suggested-books-to-start-on-software-testing.

Comment: I assume that's why it has been moved to the community wiki (see debate below). At least that's my understing of [what types of questions should be avoided](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @beatngu13 Yes. You could flag this question as a candidate for a community wiki or post an answer with community wiki checked up.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not a design pattern but more like an organizational/structural pattern.

When having a big test codebase and following the Page Object pattern for WebDriverJS/Protractor testing, we've found out that having a complex Page Object defined as a node "package" (directory with `index.js` as a main entry point) with child page object exposed through the parent one proved to be quite convenient.

For example:

```
- page.po
    - index.js
    - subPage1.po.js
    - subPage2.po.js
```

where `index.js` defines a parent page object exposing child page objects as object fields:

```
var subPage1 = require("./subPage1.po"),
    subPage2 = require("./subPage2.po"),

var ParentPage = function () {
    // some fields here

    // child page objects
    this.subPage1 = new SubPage1(this);
    this.subPage2 = new SubPage2(this);
};

module.exports = new ParentPage();
```

Usage:

```
var parentPage = require("page");

parentPage.someField.click();
parentPage.subPage1.someChildPageField.sendKeys("Test!");
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if this has any name. So the advantage is that the structure of the complex pages is visible both in package structure and in the test script?

Comment: @dzieciou yes. It also makes the interaction readable and easy, e.g. `dashboardPage.controlPanel.addFilter()`..where `controlPanel` is a "sub page object" thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Happy and sad path testing

Separating out functionality into 'ideal' happy path with correct inputs and selections and no errors, and 'sad' path with user and system errors occurring

### Mocking and Stubbing

Vital so that unit tests that would otherwise take a long time can complete quickly

### Data Driven Testing

Using complex data sets with different values to drive the testing

### The Test Pyramid, more on the bottom, less on top

```
    Manual
  Integrated
Unit Level Tests
```

### The Test Quadrants

```
   Int  | Perf/Sec
   _____|___________
   Unit | Exploratory
```

Comment: Re: Happy and sad path testing. I was rather thinking more of design patterns related to object-oriented programming, describing relations between classes and interfaces. Happy/sad path in more generic approach that can be used in manual testing as well. I should perhaphs update my question.

Comment: Yeah, i wasn't sure.  the classic design patterns are what they are, when you referenced Page Object I thought maybe you are thinking more generally 'patterns' than the strict definitions.

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorite patterns: [*Characterization Testing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterization_test) (aka Golden Master Testing) is a neat way to deal with legacy code, which is, according to [Michael Feathers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131177052), simply code without tests:

> Code without tests is bad code. It doesn’t matter how well written it is; it doesn’t matter how pretty or object-oriented or well-encapsulated it is. With tests, we can change the behavior of our code quickly and verifiably. Without them, we really don’t know if our code is getting better or worse.

Moreover, Feathers points out that in "[…] nearly every legacy system, what the system does is more important than what it is supposed to do."

As the name suggests, a characterization test aims to *characterize* the behavior of the test object to protect it against unintended changes, regardless of its correctness. In order to do so, the results of a previous (typically stable) version—the golden master—serve as the oracle for the tests (also known as [consistency oracle](http://www.softwarequalitymethods.com/Papers/OracleTax.pdf) since it compares the consistency between two versions).

Further reading:

- [Michael Feathers: Characterization Testing. Writing tests to describe and fix existing code.](https://michaelfeathers.silvrback.com/characterization-testing)
- [Bryan Helmkamp: Golden Master Testing. Automatically Validating Millions of Data Points.](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2014/02/20/gold-master-testing/)
- [Sandro Mancuso: Testing Legacy Code With Golden Master.](https://dzone.com/articles/testing-legacy-code-golden)*

*: Also shows [ApprovalTests](http://approvaltests.sourceforge.net/), a handy library for Characterization Testing, which is available for Java, C#, VB.NET, PHP, and Ruby.